# Symfony 2.6 : addError inside PRE_SUBMIT event

Tags: symfony

I have a PRE_SUBMIT event, inside I try to correct a string if something appears to be wrong. In this case, I want use "addError" in the specific field in some cases.

If I do :

`$form->addError(new \Symfony\Component\Form\FormError('my message'));`

"my message" appears but if I try to do :

`$form->get('my_field_name')->addError(new FormError('my message'));`

"my message" never appears in spite of I put all i Twig.

Do you have an idea what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$form->addError(new \Symfony\Component\Form\FormError('my message'));
```

and

```
$form->get('my_field_name')->addError(new FormError('my message'));
```

are two different things.

In the first case, you add an error on your form element, which you can display with `{{ form_error(form) }}` in your template. In the second case, you add an error on a specific field of your form, that you can display with `{{ form_error(form.my_field_name) }}`.

If you want the error set on my_field_name to be displayed in the form, you have to use the option `error_bubbling` on your field http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#error-bubbling

Comment: What you say was what I understand when I tried but in my case when I did `{{ form_error(form.my_field_name) }}` in spite I add Error in specific field, this one didn't appears. Then I know for error_bubling but this doesn't answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same thing today with Symfony 5 and believe this to be a bug or documentation error, so I reported it to Symfony: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/35831

Hopefully this behavior will be changed (allowing adding errors to form fields during `PRE_SUBMIT`) or at the very least it will be clearly documented as a limitation / possible unexpected behavior. For now you can avoid this by never adding errors in `PRE_SUBMIT` and instead adding them in `POST_SUBMIT`, where it will work as expected.

Comment: I wonder if your field error isn't wiped in the submit proccess. Is your field valid  ? The doc says It can be used to:

    "Change data from the request, before submitting the data to the form;
    Add or remove form fields, before submitting the data to the form." . They don't mention the errors case

Comment: You can check it yourself, I added a FormType demonstrating the problem to the issue so the developers have a minimum test case. The main thing here is that errors to the form are not wiped, yet errors in form fields are wiped, which is definitely not consistent.